# DB2 Z/OS native stored procedures, Restful WebService ,JSON

Tags: rest, stored-procedures, db2, zos, db2-zos

I am thinking to create a DB2 Z/OS  native stored procedures that calls Restful service with JSON as interchangeable format. Is it possible to consume Restful/JSON ? If yes can you provide some documentation or info.  Thanks

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read the [help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score -1):

This is somewhat old, but it may help: [Accessing HTTP and RESTful services from DB2: Introducing the REST user-defined functions for DB2](https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/dm-1105httprestdb2/)